# Создать api метод удаления пользователя Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Всем доброго дня.

Помогите решить вопрос с codeigniter - есть готовый проект, нужно добавить api для удаления или деактивации пользователя. Метод будет использоваться для мобильного приложения.

Помогите разобраться с данным вопросом. Знаний codeigniter не очень много.
Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Для начала надо определится у кого будут разрешения на доступ к API. Это будет через логин, принятый в параметрах или по ip с которого пришёл запрос. Затем создать контроллер API. Кроме этого у Вас должны быть константы, которые знает и API, и отправитель запроса.

```
<?php
namespace App\Controllers;

use App\Models\ClientsModel;

class API extends BaseController
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        // Предположим, что функционал удаления вынесен в модель
        $this->clientsModel = new ClientsModel();
    }

    public function index()
    {
        // Таким образом принимаем данные запроса
        $inputData = file_get_contents("php://input");

        // Для примера использую данные в формате JSON
        $decodedData = json_decode($inputData, true);

        $result = RESULT_REQUEST_ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED;
        if($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == "YourIP")// Или через $decodedData['login']
        {
            $result = RESULT_REQUEST_EMPTY_DATA;
            if(!empty($decodedData['action']))
            {
                if($decodedData['action'] == 'delete')
                    if(!empty($decodedData['clientId']))
                        $result = $this->deleteClient($decodedData['clientId']);
            }
        }
        $reply = json_encode(array('result' => $result));
        return $this->response->setJSON($reply);
    }

    private function deleteClient($clientId)
    {
        $deleteResult = $this->clientsModel->deleteClient($clientId);
            
           switch($deleteResult)
           {
               case $this->clientsModel::RESULT_DELETE_SUCCESS:
                   $result = RESULT_REQUEST_SUCCESS;
                   break;
               case $this->clientsModel::RESULT_DELETE_ERROR_TRANSACTION:
                   $result = RESULT_REQUEST_ERROR_TRANSACTION;
                   break;
               // В данном случае ERROR_ACCESS значит, что этого пользователя нельзя удалить. Если, конечно, это не предусмотрено.
               case $this->clientsModel::RESULT_DELETE_ERROR_ACCESS:
                   $result = RESULT_REQUEST_ERROR_ACCESS;
                   break;
           }
        return $result;
    }
}
?>
```

Поясню что происходит. Для начала мы присылаем запрос в index, там получаем в формате json (потому что Вы не уточнили в каком формате надо присылать), декодируем его, проверяем данные и вызываем нужные методы.

Из модели клиента, где происходит удаление/деактивация лучше будет получать некие константы. Это будет что-то вроде [перечислений](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.types.enumerations.php) для упрощения всех проверок. Для корректной работы напишите их перед `__construct()`: `const RESULT_DELETE_SUCCESS = 0;` и т.д.

Далее просто выводим результат через [response](https://codeigniter4.github.io/CodeIgniter4/outgoing/response.html#setting-the-output). А в месте, где надо вызвать это удаление можно написать CURL-запрос что-то вроде этого:

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
        
$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        
$result = curl_exec($curl);
        
curl_close($curl);

$result = json_decode($result, true);
        
switch ($result['result'])
{
    case RESULT_REQUEST_ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED:
        // code
    case RESULT_REQUEST_EMPTY_DATA:
        //code
    case RESULT_REQUEST_SUCCESS:
        // code
    case RESULT_REQUEST_ERROR_TRANSACTION:
        // code
    case RESULT_REQUEST_ERROR_ACCESS:
        // code
}
```

В данном случае `$data` - это то, что мы отправим:

```
$data = [
'action' => 'delete',
'clientId' => 1,
];
```

А `$url` куда мы отправим (В примере `http://site.com/API`, где `/API` получил из `routes`). Для того чтобы это корректно работало надо в `routes` добавить наш контроллер, а если есть фильтры, то проверить, чтобы они не мешали нашим запросам, иначе в  исключения для этого добавить путь.

```
$routes->post('API', 'API::index');
```

Шаблон для API готов!